# Get users that has one post with only one post

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

How can I change this to get only one post per user:

```
User::has('posts')->with('posts')->get()

$users = User::has('posts')->with(['posts', function ($query) {
    $query->first(); //->take(1)
}])->get()
```

This one throws an error:

"*Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [] on model [App/Models/User].*"

User hasMany Posts is used.

Comment: you may create `post` method inside the User class and define `hasOne` relationship inside it, then use  only `User::has('post')->with('post')->get()`.

Comment: That works tho!

Answer (score 0):

You can have `post` and `posts` relation in your model. In that way you can query one or many relationship, without doing extra.

```php
class User
{
    // Add this instead.
    public function post()
    {

    }

    public function posts()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```php
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
    $query->havingRaw('COUNT(*) = 1');
})->with('posts')->get();
```